# Shared repositories in repository pattern

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

Repository dependency? Lets say I have a domain that looks like the following:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Lazy<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public User Poster { get; set; }
}
```

A user with my posts.

How do I set up my repository so that for every `user`, it returns a list of `Post` and for every `post`, I get the `Poster`?

I have 2 repositories:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers();
}

public class PostRepository : IPostRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts();
}
```

I tried calling from 1 repository to the other, but it ends up in a crash because there is a circular dependency.

I'm using the POCO method of the repository pattern with entity framework.

Comment: What are you using for your ORM? NHibernate, Entity Framework or something else. That will help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 repositories:
>
> ```
> public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
> {
>     public IQueryable<User> GetUsers();
> }
>
> public class PostRepository : IPostRepository
> {
>     public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts();
> }
> ```

This is likely to become problematic.

You likely don't want to simply `GetUsers`.  As you say, you want child entities loaded with the aggregate, or top-level, entity.

What will occur is that depending on the context of use - what your immediate purpose is - you will want variations on that `User`.  You'll likely end up with methods like `GetUsers`, '`GetUsersWithPosts`, `GetUsersForImportantReport`, `GetUsersForAttendingAnIceCreamSocial`, etc., etc., ad nauseam.

What's missing is the concept of a role.

What role are you retrieving the User for?  Model that explicitly here.

Start with a base interface for your aggregate.  Basic properties can go here

```
public interface IUser {
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Posts> { get; set; }
}
```

Add interfaces to support the roles in which you will use the user.

```
public interface IAddPostsToUser : IUser {
  public void AddPost(Post post);
}
```

And your repository can be defined as such:

```
public interface IUserRepository {
  User Get<TRole>(Guid userId) where TRole : IUser;
}
```

Now, use that role to define a fetching strategy;

```
public interface IFetchingStrategy<TRole> {
  TRole Fetch(Guid id, IRepository<TRole> role)
}
```

Your repository would get the fetching strategies through injection or service location and call fetch. You can pass the repository in to provide the mechanism for the FetchingStrategy to query or have the FetchingStrategy inject or locate what services it needs to query.

Of course, exactly how you query will depend on your ORM.

But this way of modeling will help avoid many problems with loading entity graphs in different scenarios.

Comment: Udi Dahan has a slide show about the concepts: http://cid-c8ad44874742a74d.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Blog/Intentions%20and%20Interfaces.pdf

Comment: Do you know of any sample project that utilizes this pattern with entity framework?

Comment: I do not.  But I think I would maybe expose the context as an internal property in the repository *implementations*, and I'd have the FetchingStrategy implementation cast the Repository interface to the concrete impl. and get that context to perform queries.  It should actually fit together fairly simply.

Comment: @qstarin, its that I have no idea where to put FetchingStrategy, how to use it and structure the project with these new infromation.

Comment: The interface would be part of your domain, along with IRepository.  The implementing classes would live with the concrete implementations of you Repository.  Are you separating like that now?  Domain interfaces in one assembly and implementations in another?

Comment: @Shawn: There's an EF example of fetching strategies [here](http://www.simonsegal.net/blog/2010/01/11/entity-framework-repositories-fetching-strategies-specification-and-mapping-using-nfetchspec-for-role-driven-development-parts-1-4/). My $0.02 is that LINQ projections make this much less necessary than it was with pre-LINQ ORMs, but YMMV.

Comment: @qstarin could you help me out on a follow up question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706884/fetching-strategy-example-in-repository-pattern-with-pure-poco-entity-framework

Comment: I'll try to take a look later today.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, this belongs in the service layer, not the repository layer. Repository just wraps the DB.

```
public IQueryable<UserData> GetUsersWithPosts()
{
    return from u in UserRepository.GetUsers()
           select new UserData 
           {
               Id = u.Id,
               Name = u.Name
               Posts = from p in u.Posts
                       select new PostData
                       {
                           Id = u.Id,
                           Title = p.Title
                       }
           };
```

...add security concerns, aggregation, etc, as needed.

Comment: This means that everytime I'm getting a Post, I'd have to rewrite a conversion from ORMDomain to my Domain due to POCO.

Comment: AutoMapper makes that a bit easier, not that I recommend this route anyway

Comment: @Shawn, no, it does not mean that. I just chose to show what I think is the correct way to do it. The essential aspect of putting business concerns in the service and keeping repositories thin is not changed whether you use projection, fetching strategies, explicitly eager loading, or any other approach. @qstarin, AutoMapper doesn't understand `IQueryable<T>` and is not an appropriate tool for this.