# Fetching Strategy example in repository pattern with pure POCO Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, poco, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to roll out a strategy pattern with entity framework and the repository pattern using a simple example such as `User` and `Post` in which a user has many posts.

From this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628046/shared-repositories-in-repository-pattern/4628411#4628411), I have the following domain:

```
public interface IUser {
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Add interfaces to support the roles in which you will use the user.

```
public interface IAddPostsToUser : IUser {
  public void AddPost(Post post);
}
```

Now my repository looks like this:

```
public interface IUserRepository {
  User Get<TRole>(Guid userId) where TRole : IUser;
}
```

**Strategy** (Where I'm stuck). What do I do with this code? Can I have an example of how to implement this, where do I put this?

```
public interface IFetchingStrategy<TRole> {
  TRole Fetch(Guid id, IRepository<TRole> role)
}
```

My basic problem was what was asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628046/400861). I'd like to be able to get Users without posts and users with posts using the strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about strategy pattern then IFetchingStrategy must be passed to IUserRepository so I think you should modify Get operation:

```
public interface IUserRepository 
{   
    User Get<TRole>(Guid userId, IFetchingStrategy<TRole> strategy) where TRole : IUser; 
}
```

But I'm not sure how to implement such interfaces with EF.

If we return to your former question, it can also be accomplished this way:

```
public interface IUserRepository 
{   
    User Get(Guid userId, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<User,object>>> eagerLoading); 
} 

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User Get(Guid userId, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<User,object>>> eagerLoading)
    {
        ObjectQuery<User> query = GetBaseQuery(); // get query somehow, for example from ObjectSet<User>

        if (eagerLoading != null)
        {
            foreach(var expression in eagerLoading)
            {
                // This is not supported out of the box. You need this:
                // http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entity-framework-include-with-func-next.aspx
                query = query.Include(expression);
            }
        }

        return query.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
    }
}
```

You will use the method this way:

```
User userWithoutPosts = repository.Get(guid, null);
User userWithPosts = repository.Get(guid, new List<Expression<Func<User,object>>>
    {
        u => u.Posts 
    });
```

But I guess that this implementation works only for first level of navigation properties.

Comment: So this is what they call strategy pattern?

Comment: No this is not strategy pattern. Do you want to solve the problem or use the pattern? :)

Comment: :) This makes more sense than strategy pattern, at least I do not have to write a bunch of classes for every type of user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An answer in the following post uses strategy pattern to manipulate a query.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-dynamic-filtering-and-sorting-with-entity-framework